# How to run another programs in python

Tags: python

Please tell me, how to run another programs (for example: Skype, notepad, imagemagik, etc.) in python, receive from them need data and work with them?
Also, please, answer me: why such programs as Skype, notepad run in python, but another, such as MicrosoftWord, Excel don't run?
Thank You.

Comment: There is no single way to receive data from another program. Each program has proprietary protocols, if any. The most standard way is to launch a command line process and capture the input and output of that but your question isn't concerned with that.

Answer (score 0):

For some apps and websites, they have modules which allow python programs to access external apps, however it is barely used in anything other than data importations. For example quandl is a great module to import data.

If you are just trying to open an app via some sort of a programming language, I recommend you using terminal or command line (depending on what os you are on), which is really easy.

The good news is I think it is possible to run bash commands from python programs so you might be able to program a python program that runs a bash command which opens an app. If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) probably comes closest to what you describe, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. That depends on what you mean by getting data from these programs. If they send something useful to standard output, then `subprocess` is your friend, but if, say, you want to get data from Excel files, then that's a different matter altogether. You should try to be much more precise about exactly what you want and where you get stuck.

As for why you can start some programs and not others, that could depend on any number of things. Maybe they do something to prevent being started in an unexpected way, or maybe you have the wrong executable.